# How to force Windows verison of GhostScript to print on A4 page format?

Tags: printing, pdf, ghostscript

I'm using Windows' version of GhostScript to print PDF files.
The problem is it always tried to print page as Letter format what my printer does not support.
I've tried **-sPAPERSIZE#a4** option but didnt help...

Can you advice how to force GS to scale page to A4 ?

Options I'm setting:

```
-dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -sPAPERSIZE#a4 -sDEVICE=ljet4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange but changing to **sPAPERSIZE=a4** helped (even in manual is written that in windows version all '=' chars shall be replaced by '#')